# Defining generic type based on method (structural typing)

Tags: scala, typeclass, type-constraints, duck-typing, structural-typing

I am trying to declare a class with type based on some functions.

```
class A{
  def getC = 10
}

class B {
  def getC = 100
  def getB = 9
}


def readC[T <: {def getC():Int}](obj:T) = {
  obj.getC()
}

val a = new A()
val b  = new B()

readC(a)
readC(b)
```

I expect that the readC should work with both A and B. also I can't make changes to A and B class so no trait-based solution will work here.

Also, Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: A `Trait` could works combined with the `adapter pattern`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
def getC = 100
```

is not the same function signature as

```
def getC() = 100
```

`A` and `B` have `getC` without `()` so you need to remove the `()` from the type constraint:

```
def readC[T <: {def getC: Int}](obj: T) = {
  obj.getC
}
```

The better way to do this is to use a *typeclass*. Check online for a number of good tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: @AbhijitSingh I think it is just because you also did not have the `()` on the two implementations of `def getC`. This needs to match.

Comment: @Tim. Yes, that's why they need to remove the `()` from the type constraint, so that it matches `A` and `B` (which cannot be changed). Fortunately, this was simple. If the method names differed for example, one would need to create a type-class as shown in the other answer here.

Comment: For anyone interested in performance, this is likely to be *much* slower than the type class alternative (at least on the JVM), because the implementation has to rely on reflection which is notoriously slow. You should use structural typing with care, and the compiler will remind you of this by making you import a specific `scala.language.reflectiveCalls` flag.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is called structural typing and it is supported by Scala. Because there is no actual class, the implementation on the JVM has to rely on reflection, so calling `getC` will be pretty slow compared to a trait-based solution. Calling `getC` in these circumstances is called a reflective call, and the compiler will actually emit a warning unless you `import scala.language.reflectiveCalls` to acknowledge that you know what you're doing.

In my opinion, there is a more elegant solution that relies on what is usually called type classes. You will define a `HasC` trait that defines what it means to "have a `C`", and then you will provide implementation for both `A`  and `B`. Because `HasC` is your trait, you can do it even if don't have control over the implementation of `A` and `B`. Then, you will define `readC` has taking any type `T` for which `HasC[T]` is implicitly available. Scala supports this through context bounds: `def readC[T: HasC]`.

Here is a working example:

```
class A {
  def getCFromA: Int = 10
}

class B {
  def getCFromB: Int = 100
}

trait HasC[T] {
  def c(t: T): Int
}

object HasC {
  implicit object AHasC extends HasC[A] {
    def c(a: A): Int = a.getCFromA
  }
  implicit object BHasC extends HasC[B] {
    def c(b: B): Int = b.getCFromB
  }
} 

def readC[T : HasC](t: T): Int = implicitly[HasC[T]].c(t)

val a = new A()
val b  = new B()

readC(a)
readC(b)
```

This line

```
def readC[T : HasC](t: T): Int = implicitly[HasC[T]].c(t)
```

is a just a (arguably) nicer way of writing

```
def readC[T](t: T)(implicit hasC: HasC[T]): Int = hasC.c(t)
```

Note that this is a lot more general, because I never require `getC` to be defined on both `A` and `B`, which is why I renamed the methods as `getCFromA` and `getCFromB`.

Typeclasses are foundational to a lot of functional programming in Scala, and analogous concepts are available in other modern languages such as Haskell, Rust (traits) or Swift (protocols).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and proposed Type class pattern, I will look into the performance factor more.

Comment: @AbhijitSingh **Typeclasses** will be order of magnitudes faster than **Structural typing**, _reflection_ apart from insecure, is pretty slow. Additionally, the **JIT** will inline most of the indirections, something it can not do for _reflection_.